# finding difference between two rows in the same column using R programming

Tags: r, subtraction

So basically, I have this code that let me seperates my Time column into 50 hour intervals
This is the code....I need help in writing the difference (diff- I put a blank space below) function...I explained this further below

```
Time<- seq(1, ncol(analyse), by=2)
o <- lapply(Time, function(i){  
xf1 <- IRanges(start=seq(0, max(analyse[[i]]), by=50), width=50)
xf2 <- IRanges(start=data[[i]], width=1)
t <- findOverlaps(xf1, xf2)
diff <-_____________________________________
d <- data.frame(Diff=tapply(data[[i+1]], queryHits(t), diff))
cbind(as.data.frame(xf1), d)})
```

This is my sample data

```
Time(hr)  Kilometres reached
1.7        2.0   
2.4       15.6
6.8       23.1
9.3       11.5
11.6      12.3
23.4      1.3
28.4      9.7
30.1      15.2
35.7      16.3
42.3      15.8
48.2      14.6
50.0      14.2
```

So when my code has seperated my time into 50 hour intervals....I want it to grab the last value of the interval with the first value during that interval....e.g
I want this sort of similar output

```
Time(hr)   Kilometres reached
50         12.2 (based from the sample data mentioned= 14.2-2.0)        
100
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution where I used 10 hour intervals instead (as you only have one interval to test on):

```
dat <- read.table(text="Time  Kilometres
1.7        2.0   
2.4       15.6
6.8       23.1
9.3       11.5
11.6      12.3
23.4      1.3
28.4      9.7
30.1      15.2
35.7      16.3
42.3      15.8
48.2      14.6
50.0      14.2", header=TRUE)


ints <- seq(0, 50, by=10)
dat$new <- cut(dat$Time, ints)
out <- sapply(split(dat$Kilometres, dat$new), function(x) diff(c(x[1], tail(x, 1))))
data.frame(Time = ints[-1], Kilometres =out, row.names=NULL)
```

Yields:

```
  Time Kilometres
1   10        9.5
2   20        0.0
3   30        8.4
4   40        1.1
5   50       -1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? (using 10 hr intervals like @Tyler, for example)

```
# assuming your data.frame is sorted by Time.hr.
require(IRanges)
ir1 <- IRanges(df$Time.hr., width=1)
sq  <- seq(10, max(df$Time.hr., by=10)+10, by=10)
ir2 <- IRanges(start = c(0, head(sq, -1)) + 1, end = sq)

olaps <- findOverlaps(ir2, ir1)
tapply(subjectHits(olaps), sq[queryHits(olaps)], 
        function(x) df$Kilometres[max(x)] - df$Kilometres[min(x)])
#  10   20   30   40   50 
#  9.5  0.0 13.9  0.0 -1.6
```